# Can a declared function be inside the anonymous one in UnityScript?

Tags: javascript, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I am trying to write an app in Unity. I thought that the similarity between the JS and US allows to use JS libraries inside. Seems I am wrong, or I don't get somewhat. So the file is [JSmol.min.moJQ.js](http://jmol.sourceforge.net/download/) (it can be downloaded here inside Jmol package, inside jsmol.zip or just the file itself [here](https://d.pr/1lviX)) and the piece of code which doesn't want to work properly is:

```
(function(a){
function j(a){
try{return a?new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"):new window.XMLHttpRequest}
```

That's not the full code, just first three lines. I've checked the brackets, these seem to be fine.

Now, Unity itself shows me that instead of `j` (function name) it expected a `(`.

[image]

- I have tried to rename the function (just in case) -> Same error.
- I have checked [this page](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript) to learn about differences about US and
  JS, but still it shows that the declared functions can be used, but
  nothing about using them inside anonymous ones.
- The [bug page](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Bugs_in_the_Unity_programming_environment) doesn't clarify the problem as well.
- [This page](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Head_First_into_Unity_with_UnityScript) explains somewhat, at least I think I saw a usage of a declared function inside a declared other one. But again no clue for my case.

What do I miss? How can I fix this?

Comment: I think unity doesn't support nested functions at all.

Comment: You can **no longer** use "Unityscript" at all in Unity (it was never "javascript"); it is deprecated and not working.  You must use c# to use Unity now.

Comment: "I thought that the similarity between the JS and US' ... they are actually hardly similar in detail. Unityscript was incredibly silly, never really worked - and it's no longer available. You must use c#, that's it